# Positioning headings over slider

Tags: html, css

When I made this, everything seemed fine, but then I checked on a bigger monitor and the headings just went out of the `div`. So, the idea was, to make a `div` which will contain the image slider (which is done in css3) and above it (layered over the image) are two headings. The html looks like this:

```
<div class="heroImg" id="heroImg">
  <div id="slidercontainer">
    <div id="css3slider">
      <img src="images/slideshowimg/aya.jpg" alt="Aya Ueto">
      <img src="images/slideshowimg/malay.jpg" alt="Malay Girl">
      <img src="images/slideshowimg/jkarta.jpg" alt="Jakarta Child">
      <img src="images/slideshowimg/american.jpg" alt="American Girl">
      <img src="images/slideshowimg/aya.jpg" alt="Aya Ueto">
      <div class="overlayone">
        <p>“A life spent making mistakes is not only more honorable, but more useful than a life spent doing nothing.” </p>
      </div>
      <div class="overlayone" id="overlaytwo">
        <p>“Every portrait that is painted with feeling is a portrait of the artist, not of the sitter.” </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The image slider area is 1024px wide, and 500px high.

Here is the css:

```
.overlayone {
    text-align: left;
    color: transparent;
    height: 120px;
    width: 1024px;
    /* [disabled]position: relative; */
    top: 130px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    /* [disabled]z-index: 999; */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

#overlaytwo {
    width: 530px;
    height: 165px;
    /* [disabled]top: 300px; */
    left: 615px;
    position: relative;
    /* [disabled]clear: both; */
}   


#heroImg {
    background-color: rgba(102,102,102,1);
    clear: both;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1024px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

div#css3slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 5120px;
}

div#slidercontainer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000
}
```

At some point somewhere I messed up everything. How can I fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: everything looks fine to me. I even checked it with screenfly http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//amirci.demo.ba/&w=1920&h=1200&a=1&s=1

Comment: I used Firefox responsive mode viewer and the second p floats around. Can I fix it that it stick to the right side of the image slider container